# Spring.NET resource files

Tags: spring.net

```xml
<spring>
  <context type="Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext, Spring.Core">
    <resource uri="file://C:/config1.xml" />
    <resource uri="file://C:/config2.xml" />
    <resource uri="file://C:/config3.xml" />
    <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
  </context>
</spring>
```

Instead of specifying the XML file locations in a configuration file, is there a way to programmatically specify these resource files after application start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```cs
IApplicationContext ctx = 
  new XmlApplicationContext("file://C:/config1.xml","file://C:/config2.xml", ..);
```

See [instantiating a container](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-instantiation) in the spring.net docs for more information.